# MvcHtmlString MVC 2 Conversion Error

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I [converted my project](http://blog.martin.aatmaa.net/2010/02/09/manually-upgrading-an-asp-net-mvc-1-0-application-to-asp-net-mvc-2-rc2) from MVC 1 to MVC 2 and Visual Studio 2008 gives me the following error:

```
Error   1   'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' does not contain a definition for 'Substring' and no extension method 'Substring' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Dev\SapientFansite\SapientFansiteApplication\SapientFansiteWeb\Code\ExtensionMethods\Html.cs 68  75  SapientDevelopment.SapientFansite.Web
```

Here is the code the error is pointing to. It is specifically having trouble with the "linkHtml.Substring(0, 2)".

```
     var linkHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName);
     if (isActiveMenuItem) {
        linkHtml = string.Format("{0} class=\"active\" {1}", linkHtml.Substring(0, 2), linkHtml.Substring(3));
     }
     return linkHtml;
     }
```

I suspect that it has something to do with a missing reference or something but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Html.ActionLink()` does no longer return a string. It now returns a MvcHtmlString. A MvcHtmlString does not have a method called `.Substring()` (only string does). If you call `.ToString()` or `.ToHtmlString()` (will encode the value) then you will be able to call `.Substring()`. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick.  It seems ActionLink pulled a fast one on me. :)